# netgear WNR2000v4 SquashFS read-only file system

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt, squashfs

I've made it this far in trying to get openWRT on my netgear WNR2000v4.

I got telnet enabled, and downgraded the firmware to do that. I set up my tftp server to be able to send files.

however, now, I can't write to the routers storage. It mentions read only file system. quick research says that this was probably using SquashFS which I believe is read-only...kinda forever maybe?

I know people have done this, so what advice can you give me to make the file system writeable?

Comment: *"make the file system writeable?"*  -- That's an XY question.  The filesystem is typically written to nonvolatile storage (e.g. NAND flash chip) as an image.  So you probably have to (re)build the filesystem on a host system, and create the image.  BTW this site is not the optimal forum for such developer-type questions.

Comment: Gotcha. Where would you suggest I direct this question? Which site?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just go buy a MyNet N750 from ebay.  It will cost you about $20 (assuming you are in the US) and is super easy to install/use OpenWRT with, plus the specs are a lot better than the WNR2000.